# Как сохранить данные в edittext после перезагрузки активити android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня в приложении есть экран логина, и я хочу сделать показ ошибки в входа и для этого я использую всплывающее сообщение а анимированнную кнопку. Вот как все реализовано:

```
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Response<GetToken> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        custombtn.showSuccess();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        }, 1500);

        PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    } else {
        custombtn.showError();
      custombtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("login", login);
                intent.putExtra("password", password);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 1500);

        ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
        try {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("no_data_passed")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("authentication_failed")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Your authentication failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //submitBtn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1cd000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

но есть одна проблема, после перезагрузки активити у меня пропадают данные из полей для ввода и мне их нужно опять вводить. Я прочитал что можно использовать такое:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedData) {
        etLogin = findViewById(R.id.login);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = etLogin.getText().toString().trim();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        savedData.putString("login", login);
        savedData.putString("password", password);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        Log.w("MY_TAG", "login" + savedInstanceState.getString("login"));
        Log.w("MY_TAG", "password" + savedInstanceState.getString("password"));
    }
```

то есть сохраняем состояние активити, и потом его откатываем когда у нас происходит повторная загрузка вьюхи. Но почему-то такое не помогло как я не старался. Пробовал сделать через интент, но там постоянно проверяло приходящие данные и выбивало ошибку. Не могу понять как сделать, чтобы данные сохранялись и выводить эти данные опять в поля.

Comment: проще всего сохранять в `SharedPreference` на слушателе `EditText`

Comment: та я тоже думал в эту сторону, но не очень понял в какой слушатель что вставлять, и получается что данные будут хранится на устройстве, а это риск по-моему? или нет?

Comment: `edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...})`. Смотря какой уровень безопасности вам нужен... если в глубине вашего телефона хранятся ваши же пароли, то, на мой взгляд, не критично)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko зачем вы используете интент? Не проще восстановить состояние нужных элементов в начальное состояние?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, если честно не понимаю о чем вы говорите, у меня вообще логика такая - если юзер правильно все ввел, то дальше по интенту переходит дальше, если нет, то он остается на экране логина и исправляет свои данные для осуществления успешного входа.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko скорее всего я запутался в вашем вопросе. Вы делаете авторизацию, и когда приложение запускается, а пользователь уже был авторизован ранее, вам нужно сохранить хотя бы поле логина?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, да вы я так понял запутались немного) я делаю авторизацию, и я реализую первый вход в приложение, у меня есть два сценария - правильно все введено, и тогда мы переходим на другое активити, либо что-то введено неправильно и тогда мне нужно сбросить состояние кнопки на которую я нажимаю для входа. для сброса состояние я использовал перезагрузку активити, но при этом у меня теряются данные введенные в поля, а это не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того что использовать перегрузку активити для сброса состояния кнопки это ужас какой-то. Так делать не следует. 
Но в вашем случае нельзя даже сказать что вы перзагружаете активити, вы просто убиваете текущую активити и создаете своершенно новую (для пересоздания у активити есть специальный метод recrate).

Если вы напишите программно возврат к дефолтному состоянию кнопки, то все ваши проблемы с сохранением ввода пропадут сами с собой (и плюс это будет верно).

Comment: направление ваших мыслей мне понятно, но пока не очень понятно как сбрасывать состояние кнопки программно, пробовал использовать drawable которым она покрашена, но не получается

Comment: А что именно вы с ней делаете? Вижу вы меняете цвет на белый custombtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")), также можете вернуть назад к исходному цвету. А showError() что делает?

Comment: это библиотека, кастомная кнопка, и эта функция показывает знак восклицания в красном фоне когда ошибка авторизации, и галку когда все ок. Вот у меня там пауза 1,5 сек стоит, когда у меня на кнопке висит либо галка либо знак восклицания, и дальше либо переход на другое активити, либо я хочу снять галку и красный цвет кнопки и вернуть все по дефолту

Comment: можно ссылку тогда на нее? Наверное там есть методы чтоб убрать отображение иконки или типо того.

Comment: https://github.com/droidbond/LoadingButton, пока единственное что я смог добиться - это recreate() решает мою проблему, но по моему это тоже очень грубо, для сброса статуса кнопки

Comment: custombtn.hideLoading(); должен подойти для сброса состояния. Можно вставить его заместо пересоздания.

Answer (score 1):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` вызывается только когда активити была убита андроидом (повернули экран, очень долго в бэкграунде и некоторые другие случаи).

То, что сохранено в `onSaveInstanceState()` доступно в `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedData) {
  if (savedData != null){
    login = savedData.getString("login");
    password = savedData.getString("password");
  }
}
```

[Много ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate) на похожий вопрос.

Comment: Данные сохраненные в onSaveInstanceState() активити A, не получится считать в onCreate() активити Б.

Comment: Тут про одну активити речь (окно логина), как я понял.

Comment: Я тоже так сначала подумал. Но из комментариев и строчки Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class), я понял что при неудачном вводе активити открывается заново.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону Android JetPack, а именно на [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel). Это класс, который позволяет активити или фрагменту сохранить объекты живыми при повороте экрана. В сочетании с LiveData отличный механизм "отслеживания" изменений данных.